# Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0 update issue

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

After I've updated android project gradle version to 3.0.0 I've faced weird issue. When I'm trying to install my app with Fabric or send *.apk via email it says "App cant be installed" but when I work directly with IDE everything is fine.

I've already spent a lots of hours browsing all known gradle 3.0.0 issues, but didn found anything.

Maybe anybody faced similar issue?

P.S. sorry, there is no match code to share, because I think its not related on configurations, cause it works via Android Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Maybe anybody faced similar issue?

Yes, and [I blogged about it a couple of days ago](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html).

If you are going to distribute the APK, build the APK explicitly for that role, such as:

- Using the “Build APK(s)” menu option
- Using the `assembleDebug` or `assembleRelease` Gradle tasks

The APK from an IDE build now has `FLAG_TEST_ONLY` set, and such an APK cannot be installed normally. `adb install -t` will install it, but that would require the recipient to have the Android SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm curious why they didnt mentioned about it in release notes or known issues.

Comment: @Yarik: Lots of things get missed in the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to CommonsWare answer, there is one more issue.

You might enabled [**Instant Run**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523441/what-is-android-studio-instant-run). One major drawback of this feature is, you can not use apk for other device (other than the device which you are using for development).

If so, after disabling this feature you will be able to use created apk (debug apk) to other device also (by using unknown sources option or adb option)