# Is it okay to remember dont ask again?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

it's really tiring for me to keep clicking terminate in [image: this image]. I hope you all can answer these questions.

1. is it safe to just check "Remember don't ask again" and I choose Terminate??
2. Is the option disconnect necessary?
3. How can I make this dialogue popup again after I have clicked "remember don't ask again"?

Comment: Somebody just asked that recently. Here's the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64828327/14388778).

Answer (score 3):

In order to make this dialogue popup again go to:

> File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings

then on the last section of the window (which you can see in the image below) change the option to "ask".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is safe to choose "Remember don't ask again" and choose "Terminate". This is what I have done and I have not have any issues with it.

I haven't ever used the option disconnect. It is used to detach the debugger while leaving the app open. Contrastingly, terminate will close the app.

Comment: i heard that when you disconect, you would disconect some *port* and it will cause error in some function... Can you change the setting so the dialogue will appear again (after u click remember dont ask again) ?

Comment: Press ctrl+shift+A and type "disconnect", it'll find you the section in the settings with that option (and you can switch it back to Ask). Disconnect just leaves the app running

Comment: Thank you @cactustictacs for the answer. Now i can change back the setting whenever i want. Thanks again for both of you, i really appreciate it :) cactustictacs and user14678216