# My Request JSON keys (Data class propertis) are getting changed to "a", "b" autometically when I install my app from playstore

Tags: android, google-play, proguard

Issue Details: I recently developed and uploaded my Android app to the play store. When I install my app through Android-Studio (simply by running the project) it works fine, also if I creates signed APK locally and intalls it manually on my device, then also it works fine. But, when I installs same app from playstore, I found my reuest JSON's keys are getting changed and thats why login API is failing and users are not able to login to the app.

Below is the expected request JSON-

```
{"customer_password":"pass1234","mobile_number":"9876543210"}
```

Below is the request JSON when I installs app from play-store-

```
 {"a":"9876543210","b":"pass123456"}
```

Below is my Data/Model class

```
data class LoginRequest(
    var mobile_number: String,
    var customer_password: String,
)
```

Is it happening because of "minifyEnabled true"?

Also, please let me know in case you need more details on the same. Thank you!

Comment: It is because of proguard. Have you add exception for your json in the `proguard.rules`?

Comment: @שו אוהב אותך No, any post/url regarding proguard.rules which I can refer?

Comment: Perhaps this should add a clue for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70278868/how-to-deserialize-nested-json-api-response-in-kotlin-using-gson-serializedname

Answer (score 0):

yes it was happening because you minifyEnable = true and your proguard rules
to prevent this you can use `@keep` annotation on your class